# Retrieving the response from Rest API

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, api, asp.net-web-api

I am working on creating an API that call the other third party API. The third party API is an REST API and returns response in the JSON format when I call it in the web browser

```
[{"Acc":"IT","Cnt":"023","Year":"16"}]
```

I am trying to get the same response when I call the third party API from my API.

```
public IHttpActionResult Get(string acctID) 
{
    using (var client_EndPoint= new HttpClient())
    {
        Uri uri_EndPoint = new Uri(BaseURL_EndPoint);
        client_EndPoint.BaseAddress = uri;
        client_EndPoint.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client_EndPoint.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        string EndPoint_URL = BaseURL_EndPoint+"api/NameCreation?Account="+acctID;
        var response_EndPoint = client_EndPoint.GetAsync(EndPoint_URL).Result;
        string responseString = response_EndPoint.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        return Ok(responseString);
    }
}
```

What I have been doing is getting the response from the third party API in a string. But I am checking if there is a way I can get in the JSON format so I can return them directly. The return type of the get method is `IHttpActionResult`. If I am returning as string the response looks like

```
"[{\"Acc\":\"adm\",\"Cnt\":\"001\",\"Year\":\"16\"}]"
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Show the whole pass through method of how you return the data. Whats happening is that the json string is being serialized again when passed

Comment: The method is `public IHttpActionResult Get(string LabName)` I tried using `return Ok(responseString);` even that returns the response like `"[{\"Acc\":\"adm\",\"Cnt\":\"001\",\"Year\":\"16\"}]"`

Comment: Take a look at the answer given here http://stackoverflow.com/a/40836422/5233410

Comment: No other easy way of doing this?. I am getting the result but just I will have to take the extra `\`

Comment: Well you could also deserialize the rest api result into a concrete class and then pass that back, which would then be re serialized to proper json

Comment: Do I create the class with the get set method?

Comment: I am new to API and ASP.NET. I am kind of blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a model to hold rest api data

```
public class Model {
    public string Acc { get; set; }
    public string Cnt { get; set; }
    public string Year { get; set; }
}
```

Deserialize it from api

```
var response_EndPoint = await client_EndPoint.GetAsync(EndPoint_URL);
var models = await response_EndPoint.Content.ReadAsAsync<Model[]>();
```

And then return that

```
return Ok(models);
```

Full example

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get(string LabName) {

    using (var client_EndPoint = new HttpClient()) {

        //...other code removed for brevity

        var response_EndPoint = await client_EndPoint.GetAsync(EndPoint_URL);
        var models = await response_EndPoint.Content.ReadAsAsync<Model[]>();
        return Ok(models);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks NKosi for detailed explanination. But now te issue is the return looks like [{"Acc":null,"Cnt":null,"Year":"16"}] The values are null it should be [{"Acc":"IT","Cnt":"023","Year":"16"}]

Comment: Found the issue. It was the mistake from myside. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1):

you can use Newtonsoft.Json ,Just add it from nuget and add this config to webapiconfig:

```
var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling =     
Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
```

then use

```
return Json(responseString)
```

Comment: I cannot Remove Xml Formatter because I am also calling other api from the same which returns XML

Comment: ok . so just add json media formatter and dont remove xml. then use return json()

Comment: It says json doesnot exist in the current contxet in `return json(responseString)`

Comment: Json instead json (i edit my response). did you add Newtonsoft.Json ?