# Why can't parse Json and Raw Result is show?

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework, linq

I want to return the body of my result in a proper format instead of Raw result.

```
  public class tbl_Product
  {   
   public tbl_Product()
    {
        tbl_ProductPricing = new HashSet<tbl_ProductPricing>();
    }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }      
    public string ProductCode { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }        

    [InverseProperty("Product")]
    public virtual ICollection<tbl_ProductPricing> tbl_ProductPricing { get; set; }
 }
```

Below is my WebAPI function during return:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<ICollection<tbl_Product>>> GetProductList()
{
    return Ok(await _context.tbl_Product.Include(a => a.tbl_ProductPricing).ToListAsync());
}
```

---

However, it returns the **format** to be like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkDPy.jpg

---

My expected **format** is:

```
[
  {
    "id": "dc9874d0-9808-11e9-990d-014e614ad9ed",
    "ProductName": "Orange",
    "ProductCode": "A001",
    "ProductPricing":
    [
     {"id":"980874d0-014e-11e9-ad9e-114e614ad9ed",
      "Price":"5"
     }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "90d874d0-9808-11e9-990d-014e614ad9ed",
    "ProductName": "Apple",
    "ProductCode": "A002",
    "ProductPricing":
    [
     {"id":"ed0874d0-014e-11e9-ad9e-114e614ad9ed",
      "Price":"10"
     }
    ]
  }
 ]
```

May I know which part of my code is incorrect?

Comment: Text is much easier to read than images.

Comment: Did you compare the actual json result and expected result? Did you find any difference between them ?

Comment: yes, the result are the same, but the format aren't the same. Somehow return Raw result instead of Json.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkDPy.jpg

Comment: It is very unlikely that WebAPI would produce invalid JSON. Could you please clarify what you use to send request and how raw response acutally looks like (*as text* inline in the question - [edit] post to do so instead of commenting with links to an image)

Comment: Have you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40833162/web-api-recommended-way-to-return-json-string ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This helped me , you can set it globally on your statup

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
       services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore); 
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! You save my day! That's exactly what I expected!

Answer (score 0):

You should format the return string manually using the Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject();

Then the format will be predictable

(Aside: I recommend that you paste in the result string so we can compare the two in detail, and not just a picture which isn't showing the entire response; Running a diff would be my first action to test if there's something weird going on, but I can't do that on an image)